# How to find two anchor points in iOS8 for indoor map?

Tags: ios, ios8, mapkit, indoor-positioning-system

Hello every one i am trying to implement IOS8 new function indoor map from this link : [Introduction](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/footprint/Introduction/Intro.html)
but unable to find right way to implement correct anchor points on map.

Is there any other steps which we have to follow for integration in the demo code or maybe someone know how to integrate indoor map function.